# one-to-many through referance table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to understand how to implement one-to-many relationship through reference table. I'm looking on [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) I though just write on one model `has_many` so it will be one-to-many but I'm not completely sure (I wrote something but it's not working). Anyway I'm doing this to save for me a table, and doing it right and not just working.

The model is as following:

Microposts, :id, :content

```
Tag, :id, :name
Tag_microposts, :tag_id, :micropost_id
Article, :id, :text
Article_microposts, :article_id, :micropost_id
```

I can do two microposts tables with the id of the tag/article. But I think doing it like this is better and righter.

In the end what's interesting me is to get `microposts` through `tag` model. So in the tag_controller be able to do:

```
def index
  @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
  @microposts = @tag.microposts
end
```

Some code:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  has_many :tag_microposts, foreign_key: :tag_id, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :microposts, through: :tag_microposts, source: :micropost

  ...
end


class TagMicropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :tag_id, presence: true
  validates :micropost_id, presence: true
end


class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tag

  validates :content, presence: true, length: {minimum: 10, maximum: 250}
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 2):

May I ask why you are using a reference table for this? You can do a one-to-many association with only the two models you are associating. If you want to associate a tag with many posts you can just do this in your models.

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :microposts
end

class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :tag
#added in edit
belongs_to :article

validates :content, presence: true, length: {minimum: 10, maximum: 250}
validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

This should let you do:

```
@tag.microposts
```

Just fine. The forgien key will be stored in your Micro post model so be sure to add the column. You can use an active migration for that. Call the column tag_id, rails should take care of the rest.

Edit*

A added the article association. The problem you raised is only relevant if you need to get the article/tag given the micropost. The code to do that is still pretty simple with this model.

```
@tag ||= @micropost.tag
```

Using the conditional assignment operator like this will only assign @tag if the association is there. If you give me more specifics about how these models will be used I can give you a better answer.

Comment: Re-read my question. Because I use microposts table both for Tag reference and Article reference. A micropost can belong to Article or Tag. I dont want two fields in microposts table :article_id,:tag_id (and than add core too check which of them is null to understand if the post belong to article or tag)

Comment: Oh so the micropost can belong to an article or a tag but not both?

Comment: Yes, or to the tag or to article.

Comment: What do you want to do once you have the tag or article? Is it generic enough to have the same code for both?

Comment: I personally would still handle this without adding another model. If you want to use this model as a linker you should have belongs_to statements for the things you are linking in the model file of that linker.